# Can dd-wrt do a firmware autoupdate?

Tags: router, security, automatic-updates

I need to get a new company router but am looking for a secure but low cost solution. My first idea was to get a 20€ TP-link router and flash it with DD-wrt, but the latest firmware is a year old and I can't seem to find an option to do an auto update.

Can dd-wrt update itself without any user input?

If not, are there any secure alternatives that I can use instead?

I want to set it up once and then leave it doing it's job on auto updates.

Answer (score 4):

There is no official method of auto-updating the DD-WRT firmware. It would contradict with all the safety precautions suggested by the DD-WRT team because, if not followed correctly, might end up in a bricked router.

Here are a few links that might help you out:

- [Before You Download, Upgrade, or Flash](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation#Before_You_Download.2C_Upgrade.2C_or_Flash)
- ["Flashing" Your Router with DD-WRT Firmware](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation#.22Flashing.22_Your_Router_with_DD-WRT_Firmware) (Note: none of these are automated and require few user-interactions)
- [Upgrading to a Newer Version of DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Installation#Upgrading_to_a_Newer_Version_of_DD-WRT)

> Never restore old backups from previous versions! Skipping these steps could lead to a bricked device!

My suggestion would be to check for a new version once a month and then take the time to do it manually, just to make sure that no unexpected things will happen.

**Edit**:
Just for reference, I bought a used TP-Link TL-WR1043ND for 20€ with a relatively up-to-date DD-WRT firmware. You can take a look here for newer firmwares:
http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/other-downloads?path=others/eko/BrainSlayer-V24-preSP2/2014/

Comment: Do you know of a firmware that does automatic updates?

Answer (score 2):

This software will automatically download new firmware images and update DD-WRT installations. It should be ran on a linux box with network access to the device(s).

https://github.com/Lanchon/ddwrt-autoupdate

To avoid update issues, make sure you are running a relatively recent DD-WRT image before using it.

EDIT: Please note that I am the developer of 'ddwrt-autoupdate'.